# Django: is possible to have sub_apps?

Tags: django

Is possible in Django to have a sub_app?

```
  Project->Intranet->sub_app1
  Project->Intranet->sub_app2
  Project->Catalog
  Project->App
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think yes, than your settings.py will look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'Intranet.sub_app1',
  'Intranet.sub_app2',
  'Catalog',
  'App',
)
```

try it.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought about doing that before, but it should work. Keep in mind though, that each level needs to be a Python module for that to work -- it must have an `__init__.py` file in the folder.